# Underlying memory allocation during assignment (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm manipulating relatively big data, using pandas. 
Currently I have 50G memory on the machine and size of dataframe is > 30G. 
And, I want to change values of a column A using assignment as following:

```
df.loc[df['A']==' ', 'A']='0'
```

Yes, I'm changing whitespaces of column A to '0'.
But when I run the code, it shows me the error message like this:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (20, 90000000) and data type int64.
```

Here I have a question. What am I doing? Regarding to the error message, it seems to be allocating new DataFrame while I thought that I'm replacing just one column with new values. Do you have any idea for this error message?

Comment: Have you tried ```df['A'].replace(" ","0", inplace=True)```?

Comment: @VishakhaLall Many thanks for your comment, and it seems very useful. But here, I want to figure the reason out why pandas is trying to allocate new memory for entire dataframe.

Comment: From what I see, ```df.loc``` is attempts to find all the values matching the given condition. However, the assignment is not an in-place operation, so it's not optimized for the kind of huge data you have. Internally a new df is created, the values are copied. That's probably why it is trying to allocate all the extra memory and failing.

Comment: @VishakhaLall Thanks a lot for sharing valuable comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Memory Error encountered when replacing NaN values in large Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299013/python-memory-error-encountered-when-replacing-nan-values-in-large-pandas-datafr)